# How export all variable on commonjs from deferent file in one place

Tags: javascript, commonjs

i have folder with contain file and each file have export module like below

myFirst.js

```
 const myName=()=>({name:"helo"})
 const myAddress=()=>({address:"Bali"})

module.export={
  myName,
  myAddress
}
```

mySecond.js

```
const myBisnis=()=>({name:"mouse bisnis"})

module.export ={
  myBisnis
}
```

all the module from myFirst.js and mySecond.js

myLast.js

```
module.export={
  myFirst,
  mySecond

}
```

and when i call myLast.js
it will contail all the module from myFirst.js and secode.js .

thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export a function or something that does not exist in the file, you should import it first. Like this:

```
//myLast.js

import firstModule from 'myFirst.js';
import secondModule from 'mySecond.js';

module.export = {
  firstModule,
  secondModule
};
```

Or you may use a direct export:

```
// myLast.js

export { myName, myAddress } from 'myFirst.js';
export { myBisnis } from 'mySecond.js';
```